# bashrc problem on redhat linux

Tags: redhat, bashrc

I am trying to add JAVA_HOME and an updated PATH to my .bashrc file on Redhat Enterprise Linux.

My .bashrc file has only these two lines, but I get the error " : command not found "

```
#user specific environment and startup programs
export JAVA_PATH=/path/to/JDK
export PATH=$PATH:/path/to/JDK/bin
```

I'm not sure what this command not found thing is all about, I'm not even issuing a command. Is : a command?

Comment: Are you sure .profile isn't being used instead?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, ':' is a valid command in bash, so that error message indicates that for some reason the shell is finding that as a command to execute in the .bashrc shell script.  Try a few things:

1. 'cat -tve .bashrc' to see if it has any hidden special characters that are messing things up.
2. 'bash -x .bashrc' to see if executing your .bashrc directly causes problems.
3. Place a 'echo $PATH' in the .bashrc before those two export commands, and see what your path is set to beforehand.

I suspect one of a the following possibilities:

1. weird control characters causing unexpected issues
2. .bashrc getting executed by a different shell (like /bin/sh)
3. $PATH containing odd characters or values before this .bashrc runs

I believe the three troubleshooting ideas I've outlined should help you narrow that down.

Comment: some double-quotes around the stuff after the = wouldn't hurt and might avoid problem #3...

Comment: I'd really like to hear what the ultimate problem turned out to be in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Check if the .bashrc file contains any unnecessary spaces, tabs and newlines.

```
cat -tve .bashrc
```

worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this as a example - might help**

export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.5.0_11

export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin

Also read this if you do not understand:
[Redhat Documentation](http://www.redhat.com/developers/rhds/Getting_Started/GettingStartedWithRHDS.html)

Answer (score 0):

od -c  will also show you the file in all its glory in case of hidden characters.

But, put quotes around the value in VAR="" and you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is that prior to those lines $PATH has a space somewhere in it. It would be a good idea to remove that if it's there. But quoting your assignment as others have suggested is a good idea and may help if this is the case.